# connection established but browsers say unable to connect

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have a Lenovo desktop, and have freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04. In the network manager I connect to my wifi, put in the password and the connection is established.

However, when I open Firefox or "Browser" it says unable to connect. In the terminal I "ping http://www.yahoo.com" and it says "unknown host".

Things I've also tried: 
Sudo service NetworkManager restart

Deleting the "mywifiname" file in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connection

Also when I try to connect to my hotspot it connects and there is internet. And when I shut down and plug in tails in the same computer there is internet with the same "mywifiname".

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: edit your post and add output from `ifconfig -a` `netstat -rn` and `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: (I couldn't get my question to keep my edit & I can't get this comment to style so.. here is a titanpad)   https://titanpad.com/Y21Fxha3Xx

Comment: 10.19.239.58  Mask:255.0.0.0 is valid but a crazy subnet is it correct? Are you getting it via DHCP? Can you also post your `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and see if you can `ping 10.128.128.128` your default gateway

Comment: Update: I reinstalled the same is to see if I could fix it but no. Also here is your output... cat /etc/network/interfaces \n #interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) \n autolo \n iface lo inet loopback \n and finally ping 10.128.128.128 \n PING 10.128.128.128 (10.128.128.128) 56(84) bytes of data. \n and then it's just never returns to $ I have to ^c to get out

Comment: Well there's your problem you can't even get to your default gateway. I can't imagine a router giving out 10.0.0.0/8 network!?! Once connected try `sudo dhclient -v -r wlp4s0` and then `sudo dhclient -v wlp4s0` post outputs and `ifconfig -a` and `netstat -rn`

Comment: https://titanpad.com/GHz9xW5Dfq here are the results

Comment: Everything looks right. try `ping 10.128.128.128` again and then do `arp -a` what IP and gateway do you get when internet does work? also post `tracepath -n 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Ping just brings my request right back but doesn't go any further then that just like before. arp -a gives back "? (10.128.128.128) at 88:15:44:42:78::e0 [ether] on wlp4s0" and by the way I tried tails again the other day and while it gets internet it doesn't really stay. I can connect to my phone's hotspot but that is separate ips and gateway. The new IP is 192.168.43.0 and gateway is 255.255.255.0

Comment: Yeah your phone's hotspot is irrelevant. what about output from `tracepath -n 8.8.8.8` also who configured your WiFi? Is that your own router? Do  you know why it's not replying to pings and giving out 255.0.0.0 subnet? Can you get to its web interface just opening the browser to http://10.128.128.128

Answer (score 0):

Update: I tried to use other OS like Xubuntu. And by that I mean I had the live CD and then "tried Xubuntu" to see if the connection would work and it didn't I also messed with a few settings in my BIOS and now when I connect to my wifi and my browser connects to the Google main page but nothing else and when I ping 8.8.8.8 it doesn't output anything different